# Using gnuplot code with multiple code lines in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, gnuplot

I'm trying to use multiple lines of code to be plotted with gnuplot with `\addplot gnuplot`, however this doesn't work and no plot output is created. Is it possible to call a file with code or have multiple lines with function declarations?

Thanks!

P.S.: A simple on line gnuplot works (eg plot [-10:100] real(sin(x)**besj0(x))), also `shell-escape` must be enabled.

Example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[per=slash, decimalsymbol=comma, loctolang={DE:ngerman,UK:english},]{siunitx}


\begin{document}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[width=0.95\linewidth,
            height=7.5cm,
        legend pos=north east,
            grid=major, 
            grid style={dashed,gray!30}, 
            xlabel=Frequency in \si{\hertz}, 
            ylabel=Impedance in \si{\ohm},
        enlarge x limits=false,
        xmode=log,
        xmax=10^9 ]

\addplot gnuplot[raw gnuplot,mark=none,color=cyan] {
j=sqrt(-1)
zc(f,c) = 1/(j*2*pi*f*c)
zl(f,l) = j*2*pi*f*l
zpar(z1,z2) = z1*z2/(z1+z2)
zmodel(f,r,c) = zpar(r, zc(f,c))
azmodel(f) = abs(zmodel(f,R1,C1))
R1= 5.6e6
C1= 1e-9
plot azmodel(x)
};
%  plot [-10:100] real(sin(x)**besj0(x))

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}<>

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Did you enable `--shell-escape` feature such that gnuplot can be called?

Comment: @dexteritas Sorry about the MWE, I had it in ktikz, so the used packages and environment was missing, the edited example now compiles in standalone editors.

Comment: Also --shell-escape is enabled, simple plots do work. But I didn't get multiple lines to work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a `;` to the end of each gnuplot line.

Reason: `pgfplots` writes a file `yourfile.pgf-plot.gnuplot` which is then feed to gnuplot. Your code is is written in one line therein. Gnuplot therefore can't ditinguish individual assignments. With `;` at the end of the lines, this can be fixed and gnuplot produces the needed table (`yourfile.pgf-plot.table`).

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[per=slash, decimalsymbol=comma, loctolang={DE:ngerman,UK:english},]{siunitx}


\begin{document}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[width=0.95\linewidth,
            height=7.5cm,
        legend pos=north east,
            grid=major, 
            grid style={dashed,gray!30}, 
            xlabel=Frequency in \si{\hertz}, 
            ylabel=Impedance in \si{\ohm},
        enlarge x limits=false,
        xmode=log,
        xmax=10^9 ]

\addplot gnuplot[raw gnuplot,mark=none,color=cyan] {
% add semicolons here
j=sqrt(-1);
zc(f,c) = 1/(j*2*pi*f*c);
zl(f,l) = j*2*pi*f*l;
zpar(z1,z2) = z1*z2/(z1+z2);
zmodel(f,r,c) = zpar(r, zc(f,c));
azmodel(f) = abs(zmodel(f,R1,C1));
R1= 5.6e6;
C1= 1e-9;
plot azmodel(x);
};
%  plot [-10:100] real(sin(x)**besj0(x))

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}<>

\end{document}
```

Disclaimer: I had to run gnuplot manually, because something is wrong with my installation. But it worked with the semicolons and it didn't work without them.

Edit: if you execute gnuplot from commandline, it tells you that and the `^` in the second line points to the location of the error:

```
user@mashine:~/path/to/file> gnuplot yourfile.pgf-plot.gnuplot
set format "%.7e";; j=sqrt(-1) zc(f,c) = 1/(j*2*pi*f*c) zl(f,l) = j*2*pi*f*l zpar(z1,z2) = z1*z2/(z1+z2) zmodel(f,r,c) = zpar(r, zc(f,c)) azmodel(f) = abs(zmodel(f,R1,C1)) R1= 5.6e6 C1= 1e-9 plot azmodel(x) 
                               ^
"yourfile.pgf-plot.gnuplot", line 2: ';' expected
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Also thanks for the hint on how to find the error next time! This works in both ktikz and gummi.